# How do I get the Bootstrap responsive navbar to only use one column on mobile?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

On my site, I have a navbar. It looks great on desktop. The problem is, on mobile, when it splits into two columns it looks bad. Basically this is what I want:

Desktop:

```
_Brand_  Link1 Link2 Link3                   Link4 Link5
```

Mobile:

```
_Brand_           [Hamburger button]

         Link1
         Link2
         Link3
```

How do I set it up like that?

Comment: As far as I know the default behavior is exactly what you are asking for

Comment: http://www.k7dxs.xyz/

Comment: Try that on mobile

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/ this is the site with same bootstrap layout.. check this in mobile .. I think your HTML structure is different from the doc.. I will try having a look into your Html now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found your issue, You have this rule in your `style.css` line number `11`

```
ul {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This is causing the problem. Change it to just `'block'`

```
ul {
    display:block;
}
```

If you want all your `ul` in the site to have `inline-block` then you can make the `ul` only in this nav as block like below..

```
ul.nav.navbar-nav{
  display:block;
}
```

Let me know if this helps

Comment: At first I thought it would break my <ul> on /linux.php but it didn't, and I didn't even need to use the edited in workaround! Thanks!

Comment: @VirtualDXS glad I could help